# Toggle navigation for categories only on icon not on name

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I got a sidebar menu on mobile devices of my menu. The problem that I have is that the menu "Kategorie" is only collapsing when someone is clicking on the + icon. If I'm clicking on the name, nothing happens. How is it possible to open the menu also by clicking on the name

```
<li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-433 collapsable"><div class="hitarea menu-item-hitarea menu-item-type-custom-hitarea menu-item-object-custom-hitarea menu-item-has-children-hitarea menu-item-433-hitarea collapsable-hitarea"></div><a href="#" class="">Kategorie</a>
<ul class="sub-menu" style="display: block;">
    <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat menu-item-399">
        <a href="https://verameyer.de/produkt-kategorie/lymph-o-fit/" class="">Lymph O Fit – Kompression</a>
    </li>
    <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat menu-item-400">
        <a href="https://verameyer.de/produkt-kategorie/anita-sport/">Anita Sport</a>
    </li>
    <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat menu-item-4816">
        <a href="https://verameyer.de/produkt-kategorie/perfekte-shapewear/">Perfekte Shapewear – Nathlose Unterwäsche</a>
    </li>
    <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat menu-item-4459">
        <a href="https://verameyer.de/produkt-kategorie/bh/" class="hover">BH</a>
    </li>
    <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat menu-item-435"
    <a href="https://verameyer.de/produkt-kategorie/uggs/">Uggs</a>
</li>
    <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat menu-item-4817 last">
        <a href="https://verameyer.de/produkt-kategorie/sale/">Sale</a>
    </li>
</ul>
</li>
```

[Website](https://verameyer.de/)

[image: Preview Image]

Answer (score 0):

**I recommend you to look at your jQuery first.** Search for the selector which is responsible for the toggle activator - at first place, it looks like that the `hitarea` should do it. Furthermore, you should provide us some Javascript/jQuery code, so we can help you better.

As you can see in your code, your `a`-Tag "Kategorie" is no part of the `hitarea` selector as you already closed the `div` before.

The second thing I see is, that **there is an unclosed first** `<li class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat menu-item-435"` tag.

Please provide us some more pieces of information.

Answer (score 0):

Menu Kategorie `<a href="#">Kategorie</a>` must be inside

`<div class="hitarea menu-item-hitarea menu-item-type-custom-hitarea menu-item-object-custom-hitarea menu-item-has-children-hitarea menu-item-433-hitarea expandable-hitarea">`

Like here:

```
<div class="hitarea menu-item-hitarea menu-item-type-custom-hitarea menu-item-object-custom-hitarea menu-item-has-children-hitarea menu-item-433-hitarea expandable-hitarea"><a href="#">Kategorie</a></div>
```

After this you must change your css:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
  .hitarea {
        height: 30px;
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
        display: flex;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Replace your li code with this it's work

```
<li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-433 expandable"><div class="hitarea menu-item-hitarea menu-item-type-custom-hitarea menu-item-object-custom-hitarea menu-item-has-children-hitarea menu-item-433-hitarea expandable-hitarea" style="width:100%">
<span style="float:left">Kategorie</span>
</div>
<ul class="sub-menu" style="display: none;">
    <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat menu-item-399"><a href="https://verameyer.de/produkt-kategorie/lymph-o-fit/">Lymph O Fit – Kompression</a></li>
    <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat menu-item-400"><a href="https://verameyer.de/produkt-kategorie/anita-sport/">Anita Sport</a></li>
    <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat menu-item-4816"><a href="https://verameyer.de/produkt-kategorie/perfekte-shapewear/">Perfekte Shapewear – Nathlose Unterwäsche</a></li>
    <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat menu-item-4459"><a href="https://verameyer.de/produkt-kategorie/bh/">BH</a></li>
    <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat menu-item-435"><a href="https://verameyer.de/produkt-kategorie/uggs/">Uggs</a></li>
    <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat menu-item-4817 last"><a href="https://verameyer.de/produkt-kategorie/sale/">Sale</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
```

[image]